# How to make DataSourceCriteria dependent to a property in XAF?

Tags: devexpress, xaf

I use the eXpressApp Framework to develop a windows application. I want to filter a lookup view property editor depending on an enum property in my class.

this is my code:

Category Class:

```
    private TranType tranType;
    public TranType TranType
    {
        get
        {
            return tranType;
        }
        set
        {
            SetPropertyValue("TranType", ref tranType, value);
        }
    }

    private string categoryName;
    public string CategoryName
    {
        get
        {
            return categoryName;
        }
        set
        {
            SetPropertyValue("CategoryName", ref categoryName, value);
        }
    }

    private Category parentCategory;
    public Category ParentCategory
    {
        get
        {
            return parentCategory;
        }
        set
        {
            SetPropertyValue("ParentCategory", ref parentCategory, value);
        }
    }
```

Tran Class:

```
    private Category category;
    [DataSourceCriteria("TranType == TranType")]
    public Category Category
    {
        get
        {
            return category;
        }
        set
        {
            SetPropertyValue("Category", ref category, value);
        }
    }

    private static TranType myTranType;
    [ImmediatePostData]
    public TranType MyTranType
    {
        get
        {
            return myTranType;
        }
        set
        {
            SetPropertyValue("MyTranType", ref myTranType, value);
        }
    }
```

Each `Category` has a `TranType` and I want when the user chooses for example `TranType=Expense`, the categories filtered in the lookup based on their given `TranType`.

Thank You for help.

Comment: I suggest you use the DevExpress Support Center (www.devexpress.com/sc) to get official and guaranted assistance from the DevExpress Team.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If What You wanna do is filter the available categories in a lookup in a view of a Tran class, then just put it this way

```
private Category category;
[DataSourceCriteria("MyTranType")]
public Category Category
{
    get
    {
        return category;
    }
    set
    {
        SetPropertyValue("Category", ref category, value);


     }
}
private static TranType myTranType;
[ImmediatePostData]
public TranType MyTranType
{
   get
   {...
```

Take a look at this document http://documentation.devexpress.com/#Xaf/CustomDocument2681

Answer (score 0):

In this way work fine.

```
    BloqueDeZona _Bloque;
    [XafDisplayName("Bloque")]
    [ImmediatePostData]
    [Persistent("id_bloque")]
    public BloqueDeZona Bloque
    {
        get { return _Bloque; }
        set { SetPropertyValue(nameof(Bloque), ref _Bloque, value); }
    }

    Zona _Zona;
    [XafDisplayName("Zona")]
    [DataSourceCriteria("Bloque = '@this.Bloque'")]
    [Persistent("oid_zona")]
    public Zona Zona
    {
        get { return _Zona; }
        set { SetPropertyValue(nameof(Zona), ref _Zona, value); }
    }
```